Porque no se registra mi service worker en Angular?
Usando Angular 16 y uan vez instalado pwa con el comando: ng add @angular/pwa.
Despues creando un comando nuevo en package.json para poder compilar la aplicacion y correr el servidor: "start-pwa": "ng build --configuration production --base-href=/ && http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/inno-app-16".
Y corriendolo como: npm run start-pwa
en el navegador sale esto:

Como puedes ver no se registra el service worker
Este es mi manifest:
{
 "name": "inno-app-16",
 "short_name": "inno-app-16",
 "theme_color": "#1976d2",
 "background_color": "#fafafa",
 "display": "standalone",
 "scope": "./",
 "start_url": "./",
 "icons": [
    {
     "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
     "sizes": "72x72",
     "type": "image/png",
     "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
     "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
     "sizes": "96x96",
     "type": "image/png",
     "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
     "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
     "sizes": "128x128",
     "type": "image/png",
     "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
     "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
     "sizes": "144x144",
     "type": "image/png",
     "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
     "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
     "sizes": "152x152",
     "type": "image/png",
     "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
     "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
     "sizes": "192x192",
     "type": "image/png",
     "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
     "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
     "sizes": "384x384",
     "type": "image/png",
     "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
     "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
     "sizes": "512x512",
     "type": "image/png",
     "purpose": "maskable any"
    }
  ]
}

Y este es mi nsgw-config
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
 "index": "/index.html",
 "assetGroups": [
  {
   "name": "app",
   "installMode": "prefetch",
   "resources": {
    "files": [
      "/favicon.ico",
      "/index.html",
      "/manifest.webmanifest",
      "/*.css",
      "/*.js"
     ]
   }
   },
   {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
     "files": [
       "/assets/**",
       "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
 }

Encontre una solucion que consistia en cambiar la configuracion de el modulo:
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
  enabled: !isDevMode(),
  registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately'
})

De registerWhenStable:30000 a registerImmediately, pero para empezar con esta opcion el uso de setInterval no se puede, y ademas pues no funciono
Intente usar otras apps ya terminadas para investigar si en esas podia pero tampoco carga nada.
Tambien en el Manifest en el navegador sale esto:

